# Get values from url after a specific portion of html

Tags: url, get, href

I need to go to a specific portion of html through url and get the values from url.

Here is my url.

```
<a href= "<?php echo site_url('/dashboard/#tab_a/?number_page=10') ?>"></a>
```

But if i get the value of 'number_page' as,
$_GET['number_page'] it doesn't return anything.

Is there any solution?

Comment: @Raz i have set value as 10.

Comment: you are at "www.example.com/dashboard/#tab_a/?number_page=10" or you are at the page that is containing the a tag?

Comment: @Raz i am at the page that is containing the a tag and i need to get the value of number_page from url

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using PHP(implied from your question) and the 'aTag' in my example is the html code of the page you are at:

```
<?php
    $aTag="<a href= \"<?php echo site_url('/dashboard/#tab_a/?number_page=10') ?>\"></a>";
    $pos = strrpos($aTag, "number_page=");
    $subStr = substr($aTag,$pos+12);
    $pos = strrpos($subStr, "'");
    echo substr($subStr,0,$pos);
?>
```

The output will be `10`

You can see it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/982837f42eb8b41b679e58c3c426461105def90f)